# Make css frame generator in php

Tags: php, html, css

i have tried to make a css frame generator like [this one](http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/)
i have also found a same answer here which working fine except one thing

#### PHP Code:

```
<?php

function print_css($parentTag, $prefix, &$dup_checker) {
    if ($parentTag->nodeName == '#text') {
        return;
    }
    if ($parentTag->hasAttribute("class") || $parentTag->hasAttribute("id")) {
        $idpart = ($parentTag->hasAttribute("id")) ? "#" . $parentTag->getAttribute("id") : "";
        $classpart = ($parentTag->hasAttribute("class")) ? "." . str_replace(" ", ".", $parentTag->getAttribute("class")) : "";
        $my_css = $prefix . $parentTag->nodeName . $idpart . $classpart;
    } else {
        $my_css = $prefix . $parentTag->nodeName;
    }

    if (!isset($dup_checker[$my_css])) {
        echo $my_css . " {}\n";
        if ($parentTag->nodeName == 'a') {
            foreach (array("link", "visited", "hover", "active", "focus") as $pseudo)
                echo $my_css . ':' . $pseudo . " {}\n";
        }
        $dup_checker[$my_css] = 1;
    }

    $nodes = $parentTag->childNodes;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
        $node = $nodes->item($i);
        print_css($node, $my_css . ' ', $dup_checker);
    }
}

header('Content-type: text/plain');
$source = '<body class="theme">
    <div class="header class2">
        <h1><a href="#">Welcome</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li id="hellos" class="meow wuff"><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <h2>Main Heading</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p id="hello">Copyright &copy; 2012 Me!</p>
    </div>
</body>';
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($source);
$nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName("body");
$css = "";
$dup_checker = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    print_css($node, '', $dup_checker);
}
?>
```

#### Output:

```
body.theme {}
body.theme div.header.class2 {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:link {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:visited {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:hover {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:active {}
body.theme div.header.class2 h1 a:focus {}
body.theme div.content {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:link {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:visited {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:hover {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:active {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a:focus {}
body.theme div.content div.sidebar ul li#hellos.meow.wuff a span {}
body.theme div.content div.main {}
body.theme div.content div.main h2 {}
body.theme div.content div.main p {}
body.theme div.footer {}
body.theme div.footer p#hello {}
```

**if i put below code in source i got this error**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER) in
>   E:\wamp\www\ajaxtest\all ajax file\xhtml generator\index.php on line
>   35

**here is the code which i tried:**

```
<nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li data-slide='1'><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
                <li data-slide='2'><a href="#">slide2</a></li>
                <li data-slide='3'><a href="#">slide3</a></li>
                <li data-slide='4'><a href="#">slide4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="main">
            <div class='slide' id='slide1' data-slide='1' data-stellar-background-ratio='0.5'>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 slide-1-img">
                            <img src="" alt="" class="logoimg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h1>welcome to my new sexy parallax website</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="" data-slide='2' title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class='slide' id='slide2' data-slide='2' data-stellar-background-ratio='0.5'>

                <a href="" data-slide='3' title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class='slide' id='slide3' data-slide='3' data-stellar-background-ratio='0.5'>

                <a href="" data-slide='4' title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class='slide' id='slide1' data-slide='1' data-stellar-background-ratio='0.5'>

            </div>
        </div>
```

i have tried to solve but cant

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your string generation in PHP.

As you can see [here in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) if you enclose your strings in double quotes `"` you must escape all double quotes inside that string, for them to be treated as literal `"`s, otherwise PHP will think your string has ended and go back to trying to parse PHP, likewise if you use single quotes `'`.

The code you tried to change it to is littered with a mix of `'` and `"`, **so pick one and use that in your PHP string creation being sure to escape any instances of it you encounter inside your string.**

They both have their usages, read the documentation I linked above to help decide which one best fits your needs.

E.g.

```
echo "Alex's test string"; // This is ok
echo 'Alex\'s test string'; // This is ok as well (the apostrophe is escaped)
```

You are trying to do this:

```
echo 'Alex's test string'; // This will error
```

Why? Because PHP thinks the string ends after "Alex" when the quotes end (StackOverflows syntax highlighting also shows that nicely).

**Edit:** For your reference, how I came to this conclusion from your error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER) in E:\wamp\www\ajaxtest\all ajax file\xhtml generator\index.php on line 35
```

This is saying it was trying to parse PHP and hit the character `1` which it wasn't expecting. If you look in your modified source on this line

```
<li data-slide='1'><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
                ^
```

As you can see here the 1 is following a `'`, which also happens to be what you're surrounding your strings in.

Comment: i understand what you have said.
is there any others way i can solve this ??
if we use '' also "" it will generate data. without error

i will use textarea when i put all data in source.. it will generate  all css frame